# Apache module, determine name of config file passed into function

Tags: c, apache2, apache-modules

---

No, I am NOT asking where to find httpd.conf

---

I have been given code for a module that I need to tinker with and since I can't find any good documentation on the subject I am asking you.

```
const char* receiver_set_config_path(cmd_parms* cmd, void* cfg, const char* arg)
{
    receiver_config_path = arg;
    return NULL;
}
```

In this code there is a cfg passed in. I want to determine the name of this specific cfg file being passed in so I can log the name. How would I go about doing this? This function is setup in my receiver_directives[].

```
static const command_rec        receiver_directives[] =
{
    AP_INIT_TAKE1("ReceiverPath", receiver_set_config_path, NULL, RSRC_CONF, "The path the receiver will put files"),
    { NULL }
};
```

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: It seems like the name is passed in as the third parameter to the function.

Comment: 'arg' is a file path. It modifies the default file path where the handler saves incoming files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about doing so:

```
const char* receiver_set_config_path(cmd_parms* cmd, void* cfg, const char* arg)
{
#ifdef DEBUG
  fprintf(stderr, "DEBUG %s, %d: %s(..., arg='%s')\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__, arg);
#endif   
  receiver_config_path = arg;
  return NULL;
}
```

Compile using the additional option `-DDEBUG` and you'll be getting something printed to `stderr` like this:

```
DEBUG mymodule.c, 42: receiver_set_config_path(..., arg='mypath')
```

Comment: But cfg is the one I want to know the name of.

Comment: @thaweatherman: `cfg` mostly like does not point to a config file name but to a structure specific to the module containing configuration settings for the latter.

Comment: I have looked all over on the Apache websites and have been unable to find good documentation of functions, etc. for writing modules. Do you know of a place to look? Or should I just start guessing at names of things in a struct?

Comment: @thaweatherman: You might like to read here on how to build modules: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/developer/modguide.html and for configuration of modules in particular here http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/developer/modguide.html#configuration

Comment: I've been using that page as a reference throughout the process of adding functionality. I couldn't find an example using the void* cfg at all though

Comment: @thaweatherman: `void * cfg` is used in Context Aware Configurations as described here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/developer/modguide.html#context

Comment: Thanks! Not sure how I missed that